# System.FormatException On ConvertFromBase64String

Tags: vb.net, base64, autoit

This is such a great place to ask questions!
I'm facing one problem.

I'm trying to send an image from an AutoIT client over to a server that is written in VB.NET
Here is the code for the AutoIT Client:

```
    TCPStartup()
$MainSocket = TCPConnect("127.0.0.1", 9832)


$PATH = _ScreenCapture_Capture("")
$Data2Send = "RemoteDESK|" & _Base64Encode(HBITMAP_To_Bytes($PATH)) & "<EOF>"
TCPSend($MainSocket, $Data2Send)
```

And here is the code for the VB.NET server:
Data handler:

```
Private Sub GotInfo(ByVal Data As String, ByVal Sender As Socket)
        Dim Cut() As String = Data.Split("|")
        Select Case Cut(0)
            Case "RemoteDESK"
                Dim ImgString As String = Cut(1)
                PictureBox1.Image = B64ToImage(ImgString) 
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Base 64 String to Image Fucntion:

```
Private Function B64ToImage(ByVal B64 As String) As Image
        Dim ByAr() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(B64) 'Exception Happens here
        Dim img As Image
        Dim MS As New MemoryStream(ByAr)

        Try
            img = Image.FromStream(MS)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try

        Return img
    End Function
```

The OnReceive Sub:

```
 Private Sub OnReceive(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        Dim Content As String = String.Empty
        Dim State As StateObject = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, StateObject)
        Dim Handler As Socket = State._MySocket
        Try
            Dim BytesRead As Integer = Handler.EndReceive(ar)
            If BytesRead > 0 Then
                State._SB.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(State.Data))
                Content = State._SB.ToString
                If Content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1 Then
                    Dim ReadContent As String = Content.Remove(Content.IndexOf("<EOF>"))
                    RaiseEvent GotInfo(ReadContent, State._MySocket)
                Else
                    Handler.BeginReceive(State.Data, 0, State.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnReceive), State)
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            RaiseEvent ClientDC(Handler)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: I'd recommend using Console.WriteLine or System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine to look at the strings sent & received, to see if they are as expected.

Comment: I used File.WriteAllText to write the Base64 string to a txt file.
It matched the AutoIT string

Comment: Base64 implementations may vary see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Design I'd recommend to check compatibility write a file with AutoIT & with VB.Net and see if the results are the same

Comment: @PhillipTrelford That's exactly what I did .. I got the same results ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so now I used a text comparing tool, and every time on line 53, the received string has changed, as in the the 2 lines of text are on the same line compared to the autoit's output.
The autoit output is the readable one.